# How to resolve sidebar disappear on page scroll mobile

Tags: html, css

When the web page is scrollup on mobile, the side bar disappear Please help with some solution

Comment: welcome. *Please help with some solution* - need your code, which will show the problem area or minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide all your code so everyone will be able to help you out here. This community needed your code to assist you on all your need. I have a simple sample here below but this is just an example solution on what I think you need. but please provide your code.

```css
nav  {
  height:50px;
  background-color:black;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  
}

.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  margin-top:50px;
  }

.sidebar {
  float:left;
  background-color:pink;
  left:0;
  width:300px;

  }



main {width:100%;
  height:1000px;
  background-color:lightblue;
  
  }

@media only screen and (max-width:479px){
.sidebar {position:fixed;}
}
```

```html
<nav>
This is my nav
</nav>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="sidebar">
    <div>
    link1
    </div>
    
    <div>
    link2
    </div>
    
    <div>
    link3
    </div>
      
</div>

   <main>
    This is the main body
    <h1>Scroll Me on Mobile Sidebar will be fixed</h1>
    </main>
</div>
```